# Java String.replaceAll() refer the latest found group

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

Javadoc says $1, $2, etc. can be used to reference the match groups, but how does one reference the latest found group in the replacement string when using `String.replaceAll()`?

I.e. there's a string `"aaabbbaa"` and a regex `"a+"`, and I want to be able to do something like `s.replaceAll("a+", "$\n")` to get `"aaa\nbbbaa\n"`, but Java gives me the `Illegal group reference`.

Comment: Do you  want to reference the whole match? `$0`? `replaceAll("a+", "$0\n")`?

Comment: You have a wrong idea of what "Group" refers to. Groups are something you yourself define in your regular expression.

Comment: There is no capturing group in `"a+"`. You can reference the whole match with `$0` as @WiktorStribiżew mentioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`s.replaceAll("(a+)", "$1\n")` should work:

```
jshell> String s = "aaabbbaa"
s ==> "aaabbbaa"

jshell> s.replaceAll("(a+)", "$1\n")
$2 ==> "aaa\nbbbaa\n"
```

As pointed out in the comments already, you'll have to mark the capture group in your regular expression. That's what the parentheses `(...)` do. Then you'll have to reference that capture group with `$1`, which is the first capture group. `$0` would be the whole match (also pointed out in the comments), but just `$` will not work.